# Fill colours using conditional formatting

Tags: python, excel

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like below:

```
import io

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO('''\
A       B              C          
SDF     899501607.2   -26152567.7
ISB     464284188.7   -20278910.23
```

I want to fill yellow colour to the heading A, red to heading B and blue to heading C using pd.ExcelWriter.
I tried below code to fill yellow colour for column A but it fills the values of the heading with yellow color instead of just heading(cell A1)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("output_file_name.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
yellow_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'yellow'})
l = ['A1:A1']
for columns in l:
    worksheet.set_column(columns, 25, yellow_format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlsxwriter` is designed to create Excel files but it cannot read them. It also can't format a *specific* cell after it was written.

But you can use one of these 2 methods to format only your headers.

Using [`conditional_format`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#working-with-conditional-formats) (fastest):

```
yellow_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})
red_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
blue_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'blue'})

worksheet.conditional_format("A1", {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': yellow_format})
worksheet.conditional_format("B1", {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': red_format})
worksheet.conditional_format("C1", {'type': 'no_blanks', 'format': blue_format})
```

Using a combination of `set_column` and `set_row` (slow, if you want to set white color for every row):

```
yellow_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'yellow'})
red_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
blue_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'blue'})
white_format = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'white'})

worksheet.set_column(first_col=0, last_col=0, cell_format=yellow_format)
worksheet.set_column(first_col=1, last_col=1, cell_format=red_format)
worksheet.set_column(first_col=2, last_col=2, cell_format=blue_format)

for i in range(1, 1048576):
    worksheet.set_row(row=i, cell_format=white_format)
```

Comment: is there any way I could fill different colors to different tabs in the same excel spreadsheet using conditional formatting